# Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) with 5.4.0-47-generic new kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, updates, 20.04, initramfs

Since my update today, my boot is malfunctionning, and I get the following error message :

```
`Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?
  -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev`
```

and a message saying that my UUID does not exist.
So I booted on previous kernel (5.4.0-42-generic) as recommended in a question asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589899/missing-modules-cat-proc-modules-ls-dev-and-uuid-doesnt-exist-in-busybox) a few month ago.  But when I try to update the -47 kernel with the command
`sudo update-initramfs -k 5.4.0-47-generic -u`
nothing happens and the computer still try to boot on the most recent (and faulty) one.
Is there anything else to do and is anyone else facing this trouble with this new kernel?
Or did I do something wrong somewhere when trying to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Relevant bug reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894378, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894991

Comment: Have same problem with two last kernel versions - 5.4.0-45-generic and 5.4.0-47-generic do not boot, 5.4.0-42-generic works fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, as signaled by Rufus in the comments, there have been other reports of this problem, and a new kernel has been recently pushed for the users. Updating the computer should now install the new 5.4.0-48-generic kernel which work now like a charm.
Problem solved!